# Bootstrap Select jquery Swap everything at two select tag with a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, bootstrap-select

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    {{ Form::label('from', null, ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
    <select name="from" class="selectpicker form-control mySel" multiple data-max-options="1" data-live-search="true" required="true">
        <option value="1">Airport</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <input type="button" value="swap" id="swap">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    {{ Form::label('to', null, ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
    <select name="to" class="selectpicker form-control mySel" multiple data-max-options="1" data-live-search="true" required="true">
        @foreach($services as $key => $value)
        <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{ $value->location }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

I have it, I want to make it all value of select reverse With a button and jQuery with dynamically can you help me Please

Sample
[image]
When i click button will be
[image]
Selected with all options will move to "from" select

Comment: So you want to swap all `selected` entries of the first one with all entries of the second one? Maybe clear up what exactly you are asking

Comment: Selected or non selected is not important. I want to change whole options

Comment: Can't you just clone the children of each select into variables and then replace them?

Comment: Do you meant string reverse of select options ?

Comment: I added more details

Comment: I mean like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvPREO

Comment: @JoãoSoares You would also need to change `select` *name* attribute incase he may submit the data

Comment: it should be solutuion but not work with [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) @JoãoSoares

Comment: @linktoahref that's true, but he was only asking about how to swap the content. I can't know how he intends to use the data afterwards. Could be a form submit, could be an Ajax call, could even just trigger client side actions. I rather not assume and confuse the author.

Comment: for form submit I am so sorry, thank you for your time and answers @JoãoSoares

Comment: It's my fault for not noticing the _bootstrap-select_ tag. I'll investigate further, as _bootstrap-select_ generates more code to create the styling.

Comment: Yes master @JoãoSoares. IT is working perfectly now thank you so much. People know how to fix this problem now

Comment: I was working on keeping the selections, but I guess that in this case you don't need that.

Comment: If it will like your said can be bettter solution @JoãoSoares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the codepen that I linked https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvPREO, here is the code:

HTML:

```
    <html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="select-from-container" class="form-group col-md-2">
    <select class="selectpicker form-control mySel" multiple data-max-options="1" required="true">
      <option value="1">Airport</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <input type="button" value="Swap" id="swap">
  </div>  

  <div id="select-to-container" class="form-group col-md-2">
    <select class="selectpicker form-control mySel" multiple data-max-options="1" required="true">
      <option value="1">A</option>
      <option value="2">B</option>
      <option value="3">C</option>
      <option value="4">D</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#select-to-container select').selectpicker();
$('#select-from-container select').selectpicker();

$('#swap').on('click', function(){
  // get current selections
  select_to_value = $('#select-to-container select').val()
  select_from_value = $('#select-from-container select').val()

  // Copying selects
  select_to = $('#select-to-container select').clone();
  select_from = $('#select-from-container select').clone();

  // taking original names
  select_to_name = $('#select-to-container select').prop('name');
  select_from_name = $('#select-from-container select').prop('name');

  // cleaning up
  $('#select-to-container').html('');
  $('#select-from-container').html('');

  // add selects again
  $('#select-to-container').html(select_from);
  $('#select-to-container select').prop('name',select_to_name);

  $('#select-from-container').html(select_to);
  $('#select-from-container select').prop('name',select_from_name);

  // re-bind selectpicker
  $('#select-to-container select').selectpicker();
  $('#select-from-container select').selectpicker();

  // re-select original selections
  $('#select-to-container select').val(select_from_value);
  $('#select-from-container select').val(select_to_value);

  // refresh selectpicker to show the selected values
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

Comment: My labels going away :D.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, your labels?

Comment: It was my fault i should not put same div label and selection

Comment: Did you find how to keep  selects Master @JoãoSoares

Comment: I've been a bit busy but I will take   a look later today.

Comment: @MuhammedMelihTOY I've updated the Answer and the codepen to keep selections.

Comment: Great news you save my week master